# WPF MVVM Bind list of different UserControls in Windows page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am implementing User Controls in my application with MVVM structure. How can I bind different User Controls in a single page and show in a window screen. 
Like below image. I want same as it is in the image.

**ViewModel code**

```
public RelayCommand OpenWidgetList => new RelayCommand(() =>
    {       
            ControlList = new List<UserControl>();
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn1L);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn1L);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn1M);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn1S);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn1XL);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn1XXL);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn2L);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn2M);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn2S);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn2XL);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn2XXL);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn3L);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn3M);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn3S);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn4M);
            ControlList.Add(ObjColumn4S);
    }, true);
```

**XAML Code**

```
    <UniformGrid Name="widgetData" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="691" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <UniformGrid Columns="3">
            <UniformGrid Rows="6">
                <UniformGrid>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ControlList}" Name="UserControlColumn" Margin="4,0" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <controls:UserControlColumn HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </UniformGrid>
            </UniformGrid>
        </UniformGrid>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: bind what? Data? or is this just about Layout? Please be more specific

Comment: In each User Control I have data, I can create a list of user controls in View Model, but how can I bind all user controls in a single page like above figure shown.

Comment: are you sure, you mean "binding"? Binding is something data-related stuff. Your question suggests you want to layout them... in the latter, just make a grid, insert them and drag them with your mouse in Preview Window (this is the very basics of layouting :) )

Comment: No, I am not asking you for layout purpose. I can bind single user control in a page multiple times, but this time I have multiple user controls in a single page. How can I do that?

Comment: Please post some code... You can have as many UC's on a page as you like... You just need the Container for them. the Page Class can only have one Child. Change the RootChild to Grid, Stackpanel, whatever and put your UC's in there

Comment: And still.... I'm pretty sure, we're talking about layouting here....

Comment: I have added my sample codes in the question. XAML code is not as like I want in my result. I am stuck there. In above XAML code I can bind single user control multiple time. But with different user controls it is not working.

Comment: Okay, you use an Itemscontrol and provide a Datatemplate, this means, all items in the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl will be tried to rendered by the Datatemplate you provided. If you want to show different controls, this layouting strategy wont work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176657/discussion-between-rahul-saxena-and-dba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found answer.
By coding I tried much but can not do that but in a simple way I had done by XAML side. Nothing but copy the code and separately bind each user Control with only one data from the back-end in DataCollection variable. Without binding each User Control from the back-end codes.
Below are my XAML code of WPF file. where repetedly done for each User Control to bind in the form.

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" Name="UserControlColumn1" Margin="4,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:UserControlColumn1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UniformGrid>

<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}" Name="UserControlColumn2" Margin="4,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:UserControlColumn2 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UniformGrid>

<!--Same for other user Controls as above two...-->
```

Comment: You could have achieved the layout you want with two stackpanels set to vertical orientation.

Answer (score -1):

Every user control has its own datacontext so in your main viewmodel you add a property for every usercontrol viewmodel and then you bind it. Something like this:

```
UserControl1ViewModel
{
    ....
}

MainViewModel
{
    UserControl1ViewModel UserControl1ViewModel {get; private set;}
}
```